# Change Array Value

Tags: php, arrays

I have simple questions, How to change **text** if **id** = cur_three from array below ?

```
$arr = array(
    'id' => 'curr',
    'lists' => array(
        array(
            'id' => 'cur_one',
            'text' => 'Dollar', 
        ),                  
        array(
            'id' => 'cur_two',
            'text' => 'Euro',   
        ),
        array(
            'id' => 'cur_three',
            'text' => 'Peso',   
        ), 
    )
);
```

Thank you very much...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure. Like this:

```
foreach($arr['lists'] as $key => $child) {

    if($child['id'] == 'cur_three') {
        $arr['lists'][$key]['text'] = "INR";
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Something simple:

```
foreach($arr['lists'] as $subArr) {
    if ($subArr['id'] == 'cur_three') {
        $subArr['text'] = 'not Peso';
    }
}
```